# Get url video respone through Webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I use `Webview` to play a site that have video inside. And it response the URL of the video in Log-cat. I wonder is there a way that I can get the link and toast it. Or there is another way that I can get the link faster instead of using `Webview`?
[image]
Here is my code:

```
    String url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U14K1YfVjN8";

    WebView webView;
    webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);


    String newUA= "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36";
    webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(newUA);

    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(false);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    webView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(false);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);

    webView.loadUrl(url );
```

Comment: do you want to see which video or link user loaded in webview ?

Comment: link of the video response, like in the photo. The "chromium" somehow can get the link.

Answer (score 2):

You can use WebChromeClient's onConsoleMessage callback to get console messages from the webview.

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
   public void onConsoleMessage(String message, int lineNumber, String 
   sourceID) {
        Log.d("MyApplication", message + " -- From line "
                     + lineNumber + " of "
                     + sourceID);
   return true;
  }
});
```

or

```
public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm) {
    Log.d("MyApplication", cm.message() + " -- From line "
                     + cm.lineNumber() + " of "
                     + cm.sourceId() );
    return true;
}
```

Comment: tks bro. It's work. I also find another method `shouldInterceptRequest` in `WebViewClient` do this. now I wonder is there other way to get the link without using `webview`?

Comment: you have to figure out the logs that you are getting. Maybe you can filter out URL from the String of Log using regex

Comment: I can filter out the url but I wonder without using Webview is there other way to get the link. Like use an API or something